# Where is XCode's build cache? - old data is being stored which is interfering with my build process

Tags: xcode

In the past I've frequently encountered situations where Xcode wants to look for files that no longer exist and that were removed from XCode; and have come to the conclusion that some data is being cached by XCode somewhere in a build directory and that at least parts of this is being consulted rather than the XCode workspace itself.

Here's an example of a situation I have now which shows this is indeed the case:

```
I had a workspace W, containing projects M and N, in directory D.
- To this workspace I added a new project O.
- I then deleted the entire contents of directory D.
- From a backup I copied an older copy of the workspace W into directory D (this older copy only contains projects M and N).
- If I launch the workspace from the backup location it builds cleanly.
- But if I launch the workspace from the directory D, then when building it complains that project O is missing. Yet I deleted the entire contents of directory D and copied the workspace which didn't contain project O into that location.
```

Xcode must therefore be caching some data somewhere during the build process and that is why it is looking for the project 0 even though it doesn't exist within the workspace anymore.

Where is this location so that I can delete its contents?

(Its not Organizer/Projects/Derived Data as that has already been deleted.)

Comment: This is a workaround to your problem: Add new project O to the workspace and delete it removing it's reference from W. I know it doesn't answer your question of the cache but at least you can continue with your project.

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

besides the derived data some are at

/var/folder/%RANDOM%/%RANDOM%/%RANDOM%/com.apple.DeveloperTools 
/var/folder/%RANDOM%/%RANDOM%/%RANDOM%/com.apple.dt.Xcode